# Simple BST implementation using C++ Struct

Tags: c++, comparative-review, binary-search, binary-tree

I am trying to implement DSs in C++ and this is BST insert and search functions. I tried in two different ways, please review and see if one is advantageous over other.
With pointer to pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct BstNode{
 int data;
 BstNode* left;
 BstNode* right;
};

BstNode* NewNode(int data)
{
 BstNode* newNode = new BstNode();
 newNode->data = data;
 newNode->left = NULL;
 newNode->right = NULL;
 return newNode;
}
void Insert(BstNode** root,int data)
{
 if(*root == NULL)
 {
     *root= NewNode(data);
 }
 else if(data <= (*root)->data)
 {
     (*root)->left = NewNode(data);
 }
 else
 {
     (*root)->right = NewNode(data);
 }
}
bool SearchBST(BstNode* root, int data)
{
 if(root == NULL)
 {
     return false;
 }
 else if(root->data == data)
 {
     return true;
 }
 else if(data <= root->data)
 {
     return SearchBST(root->left, data);
 }
     else
     {
         return SearchBST(root->right, data);
     }
 }
 int main()
 {
     BstNode* ptr_root = NULL;
     Insert(&ptr_root,15);
     Insert(&ptr_root,10);
     Insert(&ptr_root,16);
     int num;
     std::cout<<"Enter the number: \n";
     std::cin>> num;
     if (SearchBST(ptr_root,num))
         std::cout<<"Found\n";
     else
         std::cout<<"Not Found\n";

     return 0;
 }
```

Without pointer to a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct BstNode{
    int data;
    BstNode* left;
    BstNode* right;
};
BstNode* NewNode(int data)
{
    BstNode* newNode = new BstNode();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
BstNode* Insert(BstNode* root,int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root= NewNode(data);
    }
    else if(data <= root->data)
    {
        root->left = NewNode(data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = NewNode(data);
    }
    return root;
}
bool SearchBST(BstNode* root, int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(root->data == data)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(data <= root->data)
    {
        return SearchBST(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        return SearchBST(root->right, data);
    }
}
int main()
{
    BstNode* ptr_root = NULL;
    ptr_root=Insert(ptr_root,15);
    ptr_root=Insert(ptr_root,10);
    ptr_root=Insert(ptr_root,16);
    int num;
    std::cout<<"Enter the number: \n";
    std::cin>> num;
    if (SearchBST(ptr_root,num))
        std::cout<<"Found\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"Not Found\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same problem as the other one, not all paths return a value.

Comment: Corrected the code.

Comment: To all considering a VTC the code has been corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of your implementations is "advantageous" over other because both of them are C-style, unidiomatic C++ code — they are really C code with a handful of C++ additions.  Moreover, they share many errors.  This review will (hopefully) help you convert your code to C++ style and fix these errors.

## Formatting

The indentation of the first implementation is a nightmare.  Fix it by consistently indenting everything by 4 spaces and make sure lines on the same indentation level align with each other.  Also, comma tokens should generally be followed by a space.

## General design

You code does not provide a suitable interface because "BST Node" is an implementation detail.  Users do not want to work directly with nodes most of the time; they want to work with the trees.  Therefore, you should provide a class to encapsulate the tree.  The insert and search functions should be member functions of the tree, not free functions.

## Memory management

You use `new` to allocate nodes, but never `delete` them.  In other words, you are constantly leaking memory.  This makes your code not reusable.  You should use a smart pointer (e.g., `std::unique_ptr`) instead of raw pointers in order to solve this problem.

## Miscellaneous

`#include <stdio.h>` is redundant and should be removed.

Instead of the type-unsafe `NULL`, use `nullptr`.

---

Here's how I'd put the whole thing together (minimal version):

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Binary_search_tree {
    struct Node {
        int value{};
        std::unique_ptr<Node> left{};
        std::unique_ptr<Node> right{};
    };
public:
    Binary_search_tree() = default;
    Binary_search_tree(std::initializer_list<int> init)
    {
        for (auto elem : init) {
            insert(elem);
        }
    }
    void insert(int value)
    {
        insert_at(root, value);
    }
    bool contains(int value) const
    {
        return contains_at(root, value);
    }
private:
    void insert_at(std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, int value)
    {
        if (!node) {
            node.reset(new Node{value});
        } else if (value < node->value) {
            insert_at(node->left, value);
        } else {
            insert_at(node->right, value);
        }
    }
    bool contains_at(const std::unique_ptr<Node>& node, int value) const
    {
        if (!node) {
            return false;
        } else if (value < node->value) {
            return contains_at(node->left, value);
        } else if (node->value < value) {
            return contains_at(node->right, value);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root{};
};

int main()
{
    Binary_search_tree tree{31, 41, 59, 26, 53, 59};

    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter the number: \n";
    std::cin >> num;

    if (tree.contains(num)) {
        std::cout << "Found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not Found\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7cUuoRLpC0gyWZGK))

Comment: Took all my fun away. Great review. The only difference I could have done was not using `std::unique_ptr` to make it a more interesting learning example. But in all honesty using `std::unique_ptr` is the better technique here.

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks. I wanna keep it simple so that’s why :)